# My anchor onclick shows the image but disappears after a second, WHY?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

hey guys so i have this drop down menu using ul and anchor and when i click on one an image should be displayed. the problem is when i click it the image appears but only for a second then disappears. the coding i used i copy pasted from one of the threads on this site and i think it worked for the person who had trouble.
but it isnt working for mine, why?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('banquetsix').style.visibility='visible';">6   Seater</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="">8 Seater</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">10 Seater</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<img id="banquetsix" class="banq" src="image/banquet6.jpg" />
```

**CSS**

```
.banq {
    visibility:hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your code is working but the HREF is causing the page the reload after you have clicked your link.

Try adding a return false to your onclick event.:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('banquetsix').style.visibility='visible';return false"
```